# LC3 code instructions

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, opcode, lc3

For this problem we are given some instructions and have to write out the binary representations and then the hexadecimal representations. I know the first 3 lines since we have the ISA for the opcodes. Here's what the instructions are:

```
x3100           LEA R0, L1 --> 1110 000 000000010 --> xE002
x3101           LD R1, L1  --> 0010 001 000000001 --> x2201
x3102           LDI R2, L1 --> 1010 010 000000000 --> xA400
x3103    L1    .FILL x3104
x3104    L2    .FILL x4400
```

It's the last couple of lines that confuse me. How do I write the binary code for ".FILL"? That's not on the list of instructions so I have no clue what the binary code is for ".FILL" or the label L1 or L2. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: .FILL is an assembler directive/pseudo-op (not an assembly instruction) that stores the value specified at that location.

Comment: @MichaelPetch so then do I not need to include it in the above segment? Or is there a binary representation of the pseudo-op?

Comment: You include the value given, that is `x3104` and `x4400`. The purpose of `.FILL` is to emit the given values.

Comment: There is no instruction. The first .FILL is at memory location x3103. x3104 is literally stored  at memory location x3103. The second .FILL literally stores x4400 at memory location x3104.